# Dynamic half text color in Sass

Tags: html, css, sass, styles

I'm not sure if this is possible, I want to create mixin which will set text color based on background, it seems easy if you have one color, what about two colors, is it executable to change a color of a half of a text ?

Change text with blue background..

[image: Change text color where background is blue]

I have this simple mixin, but this one doesn't work:

```
@mixin setColor($bg) {
    @if (lightness($bg) > 50) {
        color: $dark; // Lighter backgorund, return dark color
    } @else {
        color: white; // Darker background, return light color
    }
}
```

Comment: Edited, I'm working with sass for the first time..

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/methods-contrasting-text-backgrounds/

Comment: This function only has one input parameter, how would you pass two colors to it? About `is it executable to change a color of a half of a text`? No if it's one element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`mix-blend-mode`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/mix-blend-mode/) on the text with `difference` to achieve your effect.

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 0%, 50%, #6ba8e5 51%);
  width: 500px;
  height: 236px;
}

span {
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: #2c2c2c;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</span></div>
```